# How to enable SSH via terminal without sudo?

Tags: terminal, ssh, high-sierra

I want to play a prank with my friend in where I open a ssh connection with his Mac. I need SSH to be enabled on this Mac first, which requires admin rights.

Is there any other I can enable SSH without sudo or an AppleScript?

Comment: There is a reason why admin rights are required to enable  remote access...

Comment: It's not a bad question - not sure why the down vote.

Comment: Do you have a physical access to the targeted Mac?

Comment: Will your friend accept the gift of a new nice looking USB key?

Comment: Does your friend click quickly on link within his E-mail?

Comment: Yes the link I will lead him to a automator app which will save the command of `ifconfig` to a file then I will tell him to send it to me. But I just added a dialog box to my app which will tell him to enable SSH.

Comment: You should probably socially engineer your friend to install some "secret message" app so you can communicate and when they enter their password, your installer "does the deed" in a pre- or post- install script. Except that might be a felony in some places and certainly opens that computer and all on it to anyone else wanting to try to ssh in, so maybe prank them another way?

Comment: I had forgot to mention I told him to change his password to f and he said he would do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would hope not since that would be a huge security vulnerability in the OS. Remote executable access without end user approval would be a highly exploitable vulnerability in the OS.

That being said, I wouldn't presume it's not possible but if it were possible, I would expect that to be a very closely guarded secret and not shared publicly.

*A "white hat" might disclose this to Apple, the vendor to fix and then announce.*

*A "black hat" might develop the exploit and then sell it for millions of $$ or weaponize it for their nationality / social group of choice.*

At this point, the definition of who is wearing the white/black hats is going to be highly controversial and subjective. About the only thing everyone can agree upon is all hat colors gain/lose social status having found and chosen how they disclose.